# How to change color in asp.net(c#) . if treenode checked

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

In my ASP.NET application, used Treeview control with check box enabled.  In that treeview if i checked treenode want to show different color in specific checked node. see below

```
 foreach (treenode node in treeview.nodes)
 {
    if (node.checked == true)
    {
      "change the color of the node" 
    }   
 }
```

i used to check the nodes like this below coding . but no tag to color change of checked nodes

```
    protected void TreeView1_TreeNodeCheckChanged(object sender, TreeNodeEventArgs e)
    {           

        if (e.Node.ChildNodes.Count > 0)
        {
            CheckAllChildNodes(e.Node, e.Node.Checked);
        }

        if (e.Node.ChildNodes.Count == 0)
        {
            CheckAllParentNodes(e.Node);
        }
     }

     private void CheckAllChildNodes(System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNode treeNode, bool nodeChecked)
    {
        foreach (System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNode node in treeNode.ChildNodes)
        {
            node.Checked = nodeChecked;

            if (node.ChildNodes.Count > 0)
            {
                this.CheckAllChildNodes(node, nodeChecked);
            }
        }
    }
    private void CheckAllParentNodes(System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeNode treeNode)
    {
        if (treeNode.Parent != null)
        {
            if (treeNode.Checked == false)
            {
                treeNode.Parent.Checked = false;
                CheckAllParentNodes(treeNode.Parent);
            }
        }
    }
```

Please help me to solve this thing ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand your question clearly that is a bit tricky, you have to do following steps

1) Set the text of each node of your tree view like this

```
<asp:TreeNode Text='<font color="Red"> Test Inner 1</font>' Value="1"></asp:TreeNode>
```

2) Use following code in code behind

```
protected void TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(Session["lastNode"] != null)
    {
       TreeNode lastNode = Session["lastNode"] as TreeNode;

       TreeNode tn = TreeView1.FindNode(Server.HtmlEncode(lastNode.ValuePath));
       tn.Text = tn.Text.Replace(@"color=""Red""", @"color=""Blue""");

     }

    Session["lastNode"] = TreeView1.SelectedNode;
}
```

Comment: This code will change the color of last selected node, is this you are looking for ?

Comment: it will work on single node . but suppose i checked parent node want change that child nodes color also . this one is solve one other issue . thanks for this

Comment: You can always loop through the child nodes of parent and by using same logic you can change color of child nodes. if "lastnode" is parent node it must have lastnode.ChildNodes > 0

Answer (score 6):

Setting the BackColor property of SelectedNode could make it automatic.

```
treeview.SelectedNodeStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Silver;
```

**EDIT**

There is no ForeColor property for individual node in asp.net TreeView. To change the fore color you have to extend TreeNode and apply style in your customized TreeNode Class. You will have to use this customized TreeNode in TreeView Nodes Collection instead of using default TreeNode class. For detailed understanding These articles [**article 1**](http://forums.asp.net/t/949089.aspx/1), **[article 2](http://weblogs.asp.net/dannychen/archive/2006/01/25/436454.aspx)** will help you.

In HTML

```
<asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server">
    <Nodes>
        <My:CustomTreeNode Text="Node A"
                           Value="Node A">
            <My:CustomTreeNode Text="Node B"
                               Value="Node B">
            </My:CustomTreeNode>
        </My:CustomTreeNode>
    </Nodes>
</asp:TreeView>
```

**In Code Behind**

```
public class CustomTreeNode : TreeNode
{
    protected override void RenderPreText(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
       writer.AddStyleAttribute(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Color, "green");
    }
}
```

Comment: its not work for all checked node . it fine for only selected node . i want to change color of all checked node in the treeview .

Comment: How you check the nodes of tree view? You can change the color of node where you make checkbox checked using like this treenode.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Silver;

Comment: Updated my answer, please check if it helps.

Comment: i want to change the node text color . not back color .

Comment: There is not straight way as far as I know, I found something that can do it for you http://forums.asp.net/t/949089.aspx/1

Comment: @soundy: If you want to change the text color of node, use forecolor in following way:  node.ForeColor.

Comment: @Lolcoder : in asp webapplication there is no  'node.ForeColor' property .

Comment: @Adil : But i used xml file for treeview structure . i dint used directly in treeview control . i manually load xml file into treeview control .then how can i set custom treenode Function property .

Comment: You will have to add elements of Custom TreeNode in to TreeView instead of assigning DataSource/XML